# Separating error handling from generator concern in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators, contextmanager

How can I get a error-handling generator from an error-having generator, by simply context-managing or decorating the latter?

Say I have this:

```py
def foo(x):
    return x / (x % 2)

def gen():  # this generator with raise errors by itself
    for i in range(4):
        yield foo(i)
```

I'd like to do this:

```py
from my_awesome_imaginary_utils import HandleErrorWithCallBack

def gen_with_error_handling(error_callback):
    with HandleErrorWithCallBack(error_callback):
        for i in range(4):
            yield foo(i)
```

or even this:

```py
gen_with_error_handling = HandleErrorWithCallBack.decorator(error_callback)(gen)
```

To get the effect of the code below (which works, but doesn't separate the generator and error handling, so is not as clean reusable).

```py
>>> # Mixing the generator and error handling concerns, we can do:
>>> def gen_with_error_handling(error_callback):
...     for i in range(4):
...         try:
...             yield foo(i)
...         except Exception as e:
...             yield from error_callback(i, e)
>>>
>>> from functools import partial
>>>
>>> def on_error_callback(k, e, on_error):
...     if on_error == 'print':
...         print(f"Problem with {k}: {str(e)[:50]}")
...     elif on_error == 'ignore':
...         pass
...     elif on_error == 'yield':
...         yield {'filepath': k, 'error': e}
...     else:
...         raise
>>>
>>> def foo(x):
...     return x / (x % 2)
>>>
>>> for x in gen_with_error_handling(error_callback):
...     print(f"------> {x}")
Problem with 0: division by zero
------> 1.0
Problem with 2: division by zero
------> 3.0
>>>
>>> error_callback = partial(on_error_callback, on_error='ignore')
>>>
>>> for x in gen_with_error_handling(error_callback):
...     print(f"------> {x}")
------> 1.0
------> 3.0
```

[contextlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html) seems to have some promise, but my self-improvement time box is over.

Comment: Decorators are good for preprocessing inputs and postprocessing outputs, but you want your decorator to reach into a function's insides and change its control flow. Barring crazy, version-dependent, implementation-dependent bytecode rewriting, that's not happening.

Comment: An exception that bubbles out of the ``for`` loop or function kills the respective element for good. An outer context manager or decorator cannot resume its contained block because the block is already done.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to *achieve*? Your chosen path to solve the problem is not possible, but there may be other ways to solve the underlying problem.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: I thought the title clarified the "separating error handling from generator concern in Python" end beyond the means. It seems to me that it's reasonable to expect a language to offer separation-of-concerns capability.

Comment: I believe I could write such a wrapper for a large class of iterables such as `collection.abc.Sequence` and `collection.abc.Mapping` since these provide the hooks than one can wrap around to change the iteration and item-getting behavior. But I'm not sure how one would solve more general cases.

Comment: The problem is this question as presented is the exact opposite of separating concerns. The purpose seems to be to use the error handler in order to *influence* the control flow of the loop. This is doable if the error handler is in fact *injected into* the loop, but not in the desired way of *wrapping around* the existing loop/function. Thus, it's important to know whether wrapping is actually part of the goal, or just a guess how this could be done.

Comment: Could you be more precise as to how my question is the exact opposite of SoC? I know there's a lot of variation around definitions, but managing to mean exactly the opposite is a strong statement, and I would like to be aware of such a serious misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213650/discussion-between-thorwhalen-and-mistermiyagi).